# Why didn't Hermione help Dobby when his life was in danger?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-1

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 1*, we see Bellatrix throw a dagger after Dobby saved Harry and co., and in the [aftermath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWnu0SOu93U) we see Harry begging Hermione to give him anything that could save Dobby, but Hermione standing still.

Why is this? Is it too late for anything to be done? Is it because Dobby is not a human? We have definitely seen Hermione heal Ron before.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Several things explaining why she wasn't able to heal Dobby

- Even though she had a general knowledge of various spells, she was not trained for healing - even in the books she mentions she never attempted to further her knowledge of healing wounds. Hermione knows how to use healing potions, but she isn't Madam Pomfrey. Similarly, she was not able to save Snape in deathly hallows part 2.
- Hermione was definitely in shock, because she was tortured by Bellatrix several minutes ago - she needed help herself first
- Dittany heals a lot of things, but a knife through the chest may not be one of them. Also as Hermione mentions, it may the injuries make even worse

  > " 'It's all I feel safe doing,' said Hermione shakily. 'There are
  >   spells that would put him completely right, but I daren't try in case
  >   I do them wrong and **cause more damage**.... He's lost so much blood
  >   already...."
- Most important - she was not there while Dobby was dying at the beach, they went to house together with Ron (she is present just in the film)
- [Here is the list of all known healing spells](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_spell). None of them can probably heal such a fatal injury Dobby has suffered.
- In the book Hermione stuffed the beaded bag in her sock to save it. In the film, the snatchers got the beaded bag.

---

Further reading

- Science Fiction and Fantasy: [Why didn't Hermione use her Dittany on Dobby when he was dying?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141211/why-didnt-hermione-use-her-dittany-on-dobby-when-he-was-dying)
- Quora: [Why didn't Hermione heal Dobby in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1?](https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Hermione-heal-Dobby-in-Harry-Potter-and-the-Deathly-Hallows-Part-1)

Comment: I always figured Dittany was just for Apparition

Comment: @AzorAhai *> There may be a certain amount of scarring, but if you take dittany immediately we might avoid even that..* Severus Snape to Draco Malfoy after Sectumsempra, HBP.

Comment: @AzorAhai Hermione also used it to treat the burns the trio got while breaking into Gringotts, as well as to treat the snake bite Harry got from Nagini in Bathilda’s house.

Comment: You can add one space character in front of the first `>` to bring the quote block into the list.

Comment: @unor Nice- next time you can edit the answer directly :)

Comment: @FilipKočica: I think I can’t, as a suggested edit needs to change at least 6 characters -- and in your answer there wasn’t anything else I would have changed.

Answer (score 8):

> Why didn't Hermione do anything while Dobby was dying?

Can she even do it?

First she is not a healer and only thing she ever used in film to heal was [Dittany](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dittany) but it was only used for a hand wound which was not as fatal as chest wound of Dobby.

Dittany's use is also covered in similar question from Science Fiction and Fantasy :

[Why didn't Hermione use her Dittany on Dobby when he was dying?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141211/6006)

So here were are expecting a lot from Hermione like Harry did.